# TypeError: (0 , _toolkit.combineReducers) is not a function

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

Just started to integrate redux-toolkit in the new React Native app following [Advanced Tutorial](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/advanced-tutorial) and immediately faced an `TypeError: (0 , _toolkit.combineReducers) is not a function` error. Simplified structure of files where I use redux-toolkit is next:

`src/store/UserReducer.ts`:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

let initialState = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setIsLoggedIn(state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) {
      state.isLoggedIn = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setIsLoggedIn } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

`src/store/rootReducer.ts`:

```
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import UserReducer from './UserReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ user: UserReducer });

export default rootReducer;
```

`src/store/index.ts`:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

const store = configureStore({ reducer: rootReducer });

export default store;
```

`App.tsx`

```
...
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './src/store';
...

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      ...
    </Provider>
  )
};

export default App;
```

`"redux": "^4.0.5"`, `"react-redux": "^7.2.2"` and `"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0"` are installed.

Comment: Do you have any folders named 'redux' in your project structure by any chance? This seems to be a common issue: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1681#issuecomment-216508641

Comment: @nipuna777 you're totally right, thanks! Couldn't find that Dan's post because the error is different since toolkit release.